# UICollectionView deleting items sometimes happens without animation

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview

I have a pretty basic UICollectionView. Here's two methods that delete and insert some items in one section.

```
#pragma mark - SCRBShowHideAdditionalTilesDelegate


- (void)showAdditionalTiles {

    self.additionalTilesHidden = NO;

    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

        [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:self.indexPathsOfTilesToHide];

    } completion:nil];

}

- (void)hideAdditionalTiles {


    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

         self.additionalTilesHidden = YES;
        [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:self.indexPathsOfTilesToHide];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];


    }];

}
```

Property `self.additionalTilesHidden` changes a number of items to appropriate number in a data source methods. It does work as intended, but sometimes deletion happens with no animation, just instantly jumps to final state, and sometimes it does animate. Insertion animates all the time. I use standard `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. I can't figure out why this is inconsistent and what am I doing wrong here.

**UPDATE:**
It was empirically found that animation occurs only if 2 or less items that about to be deleted are visible. If 3 or more are visible - no animation happens. I added a gif to better understand the layout.

[image]

Comment: does this happen to items which are out of visible area of the screen? The possible workaround is to create your own custom  `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` similar to https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout

Comment: @teamnorge hm, your question made me do a little investigation. It seems like if there's 2 or less items that have to disappear are visible - animation works, if more than 2 - no animation.